# pluralize in PHP

Tags: php

I have a lot of information to display from a database. Some are french, other are english. Some are a unique, some a list...

The question : how do you manage all that different option in PHP

IF
ELSE
SWITCH
ARRAY (with all the text)

other method ...

now the problem rise on a list of odors, some have one (odor) other have many (odors) putting the s or not is a pain..... help !

thanks