# Parsing plain text in such a way that will recognise a custom if statement

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have the following string:

```
$string = "The man has {NUM_DOGS} dogs."
```

I'm parsing this by running it through the following function:

```
function parse_text($string)
{
    global $num_dogs;

    $string = str_replace('{NUM_DOGS}', $num_dogs, $string);

    return $string;
}

parse_text($string);
```

Where `$num_dogs` is a preset variable. Depending on `$num_dogs`, this could return any of the following strings:

- The man has 1 dogs.
- The man has 2 dogs.
- The man has 500 dogs.

The problem is that in the case that "the man has 1 dogs", *dog* is pluralised, which is undesired. I know that this could be solved simply by not using the `parse_text` function and instead doing something like:

```
if($num_dogs = 1){
    $string = "The man has 1 dog.";
}else{
    $string = "The man has $num_dogs dogs.";
}
```

But in my application I'm parsing more than just `{NUM_DOGS}` and it'd take a lot of lines to write all the conditions.

I need a shorthand way which I can write into the initial `$string` which I can run through a parser, which ideally wouldn't limit me to just two true/false possibilities.

For example, let

```
$string = 'The man has {NUM_DOGS} [{NUM_DOGS}|0=>"dogs",1=>"dog called fred",2=>"dogs called fred and harry",3=>"dogs called fred, harry and buster"].';
```

Is it clear what's happened at the end? I've attempted to initiate the creation of an array using the part inside the square brackets that's after the vertical bar, then compare the key of the new array with the parsed value of {NUM_DOGS} (which by now will be the $num_dogs variable at the left of the vertical bar), and return the value of the array entry with that key.

If that's not totally confusing, is it possible using the preg_* functions?

Comment: I get how `{NUM_DOGS}` is passed to the function, but when you start mentioning dog names and such, you just completely threw me off. How are they passed to the function?

Comment: If the string is considered super,super safe. This can very easily be done using `eval` http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: They're not individually passed to the function, they just go along for the ride because they're contained within `$string`. Let `$num_dogs = 2`. After going through `parse_text` `$string = The man has 2 [2|0=>"dogs",1=>"dog called fred",2=>"dogs called fred and harry",3=>"dogs called fred, harry and buster"].`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: Just windows uses this format sometimes file(s). Maybe dog(s) :)

Comment: @Ankush - yes, that would be adequate if I only had two options, dog or dogs. I want to show a custom message for each number of dogs.

Comment: Can you have something like `'The man has {NUM_DOGS} {DOGS}'`, with another `str_replace` for `{DOGS}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The premise of your question is that you want to **match** a specific **pattern** and then **replace** it after performing **additional processing** on the matched text.

Seems like an ideal candidate for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

The regular expressions for capturing matched parenthesis, quotes, braces etc. can become quite complicated, and to do it all with a regular expression is in fact quite inefficient. In fact you'd need to write a proper parser if that's what you require.

For this question I'm going to assume a limited level of complexity, and tackle it with a two stage parse using regex.

---

First of all, the most simple regex I can think off for capturing tokens between curly braces.

```
/{([^}]+)}/
```

Lets break that down.

```
{        # A literal opening brace
(        # Begin capture
  [^}]+  # Everything that's not a closing brace (one or more times)
)        # End capture
}        # Literal closing brace
```

When applied to a string with `preg_match_all` the results look something like:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    0 => 'A string {TOK_ONE}',
    1 => ' with {TOK_TWO|0=>"no", 1=>"one", 2=>"two"}',
  ),
  1 => array (
    0 => 'TOK_ONE',
    1 => 'TOK_TWO|0=>"no", 1=>"one", 2=>"two"',
  ),
)
```

Looks good so far.

Please note that if you have nested braces in your strings, i.e. `{TOK_TWO|0=>"hi {x} y"}`, this regex will not work. If this wont be a problem, skip down to the next section.

It is possible to do top-level matching, but the only way I have ever been able to do it is via recursion. Most regex veterans will tell you that as soon as you add recursion to a regex, it stops being a regex.

This is where the additional processing complexity kicks in, and with long complicated strings it's very easy to run out of stack space and crash your program. Use it carefully if you need to use it at all.

The recursive regex [taken from one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468459/599857) and modified a little.

```
`/{((?:[^{}]*|(?R))*)}/`
```

Broken down.

```
{                   # literal brace
(                   # begin capture
    (?:             # don't create another capture set
        [^{}]*      # everything not a brace
        |(?R)       # OR recurse
    )*              # none or more times
)                   # end capture
}                   # literal brace
```

And this time the ouput only matches top-level braces

```
array (
  0 => array (
    0 => '{TOK_ONE|0=>"a {nested} brace"}',
  ),
  1 => array (
    0 => 'TOK_ONE|0=>"a {nested} brace"',
  ),
)
```

Again, don't use the recursive regex unless you have to. (Your system may not even support them if it has an old PCRE library)

---

With that out of the way we need to work out if the token has options associated with it. Instead of having two fragments to be matched as per your question, I'd recommend keeping the options with the token as per my examples. `{TOKEN|0=>"option"}`

Lets assume `$match` contains a matched token, if we check for a pipe `|`, and take the substring of everything after it we'll be left with your list of options, again we can use regex to parse them out. (Don't worry I'll bring everything together at the end)

`/(\d)+\s*=>\s*"([^"]*)",?/`

Broken down.

```
(\d)+    # Capture one or more decimal digits
\s*      # Any amount of whitespace (allows you to do 0    =>    "")
=>       # Literal pointy arrow
\s*      # Any amount of whitespace
"        # Literal quote
([^"]*)  # Capture anything that isn't a quote
"        # Literal quote
,?       # Maybe followed by a comma
```

And an example match

```
array (
  0 => array (
    0 => '0=>"no",',
    1 => '1 => "one",',
    2 => '2=>"two"',
  ),
  1 => array (
    0 => '0',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '2',
  ),
  2 => array (
    0 => 'no',
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
  ),
)
```

If you want to use quotes inside your quotes, you'll have to make your own recursive regex for it.

---

Wrapping up, here's a working example.

Some initialisation code.

```
$options = array(
    'WERE' => 1,
    'TYPE' => 'cat',
    'PLURAL' => 1,
    'NAME' => 2
);

$string = 'There {WERE|0=>"was a",1=>"were"} ' .
    '{TYPE}{PLURAL|1=>"s"} named bob' . 
    '{NAME|1=>" and bib",2=>" and alice"}';
```

And everything together.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/{([^}]+)}/', function($match) use ($options) {
    $match = $match[1];

    if (false !== $pipe = strpos($match, '|')) {
        $tokens = substr($match, $pipe + 1);
        $match = substr($match, 0, $pipe);
    } else {
        $tokens = array();
    }

    if (isset($options[$match])) {
        if ($tokens) {
            preg_match_all('/(\d)+\s*=>\s*"([^"]*)",?/', $tokens, $tokens);

            $tokens = array_combine($tokens[1], $tokens[2]);

            return $tokens[$options[$match]];
        }
        return $options[$match];
    }
    return '';
}, $string);
```

Please note the error checking is minimal, there will be unexpected results if you pick options that don't exist.

There's probably a lot simpler way to do all of this, but I just took the idea and ran with it.

Comment: For nested quotes you could probably quite easily allow an escape character (\ is traditional, of course), without needing a recursive regex. Won't work for the nested braces though.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it is a bit debatable, but if you can easily avoid it, just pass `$num_dogs` as an argument to the function as most people believe global variables are evil!

Next, for the getting the "s", I generally do something like this:

```
$dogs_plural = ($num_dogs == 1) ? '' : 's';
```

Then just do something like this:

```
$your_string = "The man has $num_dogs dog$dogs_plural";
```

It's essentially the same thing as doing an if/else block, but less lines of code and you only have to write the text once.

As for the other part, I am STILL confused about what you're trying to do, but I believe you are looking for some sort of way to convert

```
{NUM_DOGS}|0=>"dogs",1=>"dog called fred",2=>"dogs called fred and harry",3=>"dogs called fred, harry and buster"]
```

into:

```
switch $num_dogs {
    case 0:
        return 'dogs';
        break;
    case 1:
        return 'dog called fred';
        break;
    case 2:
        return 'dogs called fred and harry';
        break;
    case 3:
        return 'dogs called fred, harry and buster';
        break;
}
```

The easiest way is to try to use a combination of `explode()` and regex to then get it to do something like I have above.

Answer (score 6):

In a pinch, I have done something similar to what you're asking with an implementation vaguely like the code below.

This is nowhere near as feature rich as @Mike's answer, but it has done the trick in the past.

```
/**
 * This function pluralizes words, as appropriate.
 *
 * It is a completely naive, example-only implementation.
 * There are existing "inflector" implementations that do this
 * quite well for many/most *English* words.
 */
function pluralize($count, $word)
{
    if ($count === 1)
    {
        return $word;
    }
    return $word . 's';
}

/**
 * Matches template patterns in the following forms:
 *   {NAME}       - Replaces {NAME} with value from $values['NAME']
 *   {NAME:word}  - Replaces {NAME:word} with 'word', pluralized using the pluralize() function above.
 */
function parse($template, array $values)
{
    $callback = function ($matches) use ($values) {
        $number = $values[$matches['name']];
        if (array_key_exists('word', $matches)) {
            return pluralize($number, $matches['word']);
        }
        return $number;
    };

    $pattern = '/\{(?<name>.+?)(:(?<word>.+?))?\}/i';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $template);
}
```

Here are some examples similar to your original question...

```
echo parse(
    'The man has {NUM_DOGS} {NUM_DOGS:dog}.' . PHP_EOL,
    array('NUM_DOGS' => 2)
);

echo parse(
    'The man has {NUM_DOGS} {NUM_DOGS:dog}.' . PHP_EOL,
    array('NUM_DOGS' => 1)
);
```

The output is:

> The man has 2 dogs.
>
> The man has 1 dog.

It may be worth mentioning that in larger projects I've invariably ended up ditching any custom rolled inflection in favour of [GNU gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) which seems to be the most sane way forward once multi-lingual is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

***This was copied from an answer posted by flussence back in 2009 in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534127/pluralize-in-php):***

You might want to look at the [gettext extension](http://php.net/gettext). More specifically, it sounds like `ngettext()` will do what you want: it pluralises words correctly as long as you have a number to count from.

```
print ngettext('odor', 'odors', 1); // prints "odor"
print ngettext('odor', 'odors', 4); // prints "odors"
print ngettext('%d cat', '%d cats', 4); // prints "4 cats"
```

You can also make it handle translated plural forms correctly, which is its main purpose, though it's quite a lot of extra work to do.