# A good way to get the text between 2-3 sets of curly brackets

Tags: php, string, random, formatting

I'm working with an API that returns text in the following format:

> > {I want|I need} to make this {stupid|awesome|irritating} sentence
> >     {formatting {rapidly|quickly} and random|spin and be random}

Using PHP, I need to format the string like:

```
"I need to make this irritating sentence formatting quickly";
```

OR

```
"I want to make this awesome sentence spin and be random";
```

from the initial text.

I would have no problem if the curly brackets couldn't contain another set of curly brackets.  Any advice or any piece of code that could help me solve this problem?

Comment: I've never seen a format like that o.o Can you request it in JSON or XMLRPC?

Comment: I've seen something like this before...

Comment: Aha! [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11897951/1421049)

Comment: I'm {wondering|seeing} you may have an {extra|missing} {curly brackets|mustaches} somewhere near { {{{formatting{{{random|||spin}}} | random|||spin and be random}}} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your source string is like this:

```
{I want|I need} to make this {stupid|awesome|irritating}
sentence formatting {rapidly|quickly} and {random|spin and be random}
```

otherwise the brackets are nested and your output example does not match how you put them in source string. Then use `preg_match_all()` like this:

```
preg_match_all("/{.*}/U",$sourceString, $result, 
                      PREG_PATTERN_ORDER|PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

which for your `$sourceString` would produce:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "{I want|I need}"
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(27) "{stupid|awesome|irritating}"
      [1]=>
      int(29)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "{rapidly|quickly}"
      [1]=>
      int(77)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(27) "{random|spin and be random}"
      [1]=>
      int(99)
    }
  }
}
```

And you get all items. Then you can process each entry, strip "{" and "}", `explode()` on "|" to get array of options to choose from. Then you pick what you want and replace formerly found item with it. Note, I capture offset where matching pattern is found, because you cannot just eventually do `str_replace()` because I assume you want to be able to use the same entry in many places (i.e. "{this|that} foo {this|that}". `str_replace()` would replace both while I think it is not desired. So we got offset in the string, length of string can be easily computed but this is sufficient to do some surgery, and cut off our entry and put replacement. Other, cleaner approach is to use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and put all that "logic" in the callback so you could do whole processing in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not done in a few lines of code. Because you have nested code, you even couldn't use regular expressions to parse the input properly.

A simple idea of me was to convert the input to XML and use the SimpleXML class to parse the input and build on top of that an AST which could easily converted to your wanted output.

A simple example

```php
$xml = "<root>" .
        str_replace(
                array("{", "}"),
                array("<t>", "</t>"),
                $input) . 
        "</root>";

$dom = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this works based on the sentence you provided, but I would test it more before moving to production. (for instance, you can't have any other `{`, `}` or `|`)

http://codepad.viper-7.com/HpJKOt

```
<?php

$string = "{I want|I need} to make this {stupid|awesome|irritating} sentence {formatting {rapidly|quickly} and random|spin and be random}";

echo parseString($string);

function parseString($string) {

    // look for {abc|def}
    if (preg_match_all("/\{(([^\{\|\}]*)\|)+([^\{\|\}]*)\}/", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {

        // trim {} and put into array
        $options = explode('|', substr($matches[0][0][0], 1, -1));

        // randomize
        shuffle($options);

        // make the replacement
        $string = str_replace($matches[0][0][0], $options[0], $string);

        // check again
        return parseString($string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: You will fail on "{this|that} foo {this|that}". And recurrence... Not sure about resource usage on longer texts. preg_replace_callback() would be cleaner

Comment: Your example seems to work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FaOc9I