# PHP Date difference formatting. Plural and singular

Tags: php, format

Would want to make php more interactive

Looking for a way to list result when there is only one day left
Result: 1 day remaining

Else:
Result: n days remaining

Partial Code

```
$daysleft = $date2->diff($date1);
echo $daysleft->format('%a days'),' remaining';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pluralize in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534127/pluralize-in-php)

Comment: @aviram not really. im slightly confused by the diff function within the array. was looking for a way to extract the date differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just manually generate your text:

```
$daysleft = $date2->diff($date1)->format('%a');
echo $daysleft.' '.($daysleft == 1 ? 'day' : 'days').' remaining';
```

For this simple use case, this should be the best approach...